# How to change default name NetBeans project?

Tags: netbeans

I'd like to change the "JavaApplicationXXX" that appears when I create a new project in NetBeans, anyone knows where is that default name located or where could I change it?

I've already checked on the web and in my netBeans folder, looking for some configuration archive, but all I found is to change the route of the jdk and the like, but not the default name of the project, nor the counter of the number of applications I've created. I think it should be somewhere inside this folder, but no matter how I search, it is of no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is not configurable as an end user. It's located in the bundle `netbeans/java/java.j2seproject/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/ui/wizards/Bundle.properties` and is called `TXT_JavaApplication` ([direct link](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/78157893a0221c36134e710410520757b1b96425/java/java.j2seproject/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/ui/wizards/Bundle.properties#L76)).

The number itself will be determined in  [netbeans/java/java.j2seproject/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/ui/wizards/PanelProjectLocationVisual.java](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/accdbada0a9c5105bd3f06e435024230c1618316/java/java.j2seproject/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/ui/wizards/PanelProjectLocationVisual.java#L292)